Start an ASP.NET Core `WebApplication` within a test with random port to listen
I have a standard ASP.NET Core 8 WebApplication.CreateBuilder (args) application.
I want to start it within my test and listen on a random port.
I dig into Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing and found the WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>.EnsureServer method that uses DeferredHostBuilder for my case.
So I reflected that code as follows:
module DeferredHostBuilder =

    let private ``type`` =
        typedefof<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory<_>>.Assembly.GetType
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.DeferredHostBuilder"

    let private ctor = ``type``.GetConstructor Array.empty
    let private ConfigureHostBuilderMethod = ``type``.GetMethod "ConfigureHostBuilder"
    let private EntryPointCompletedMethod = ``type``.GetMethod "EntryPointCompleted"
    let private SetHostFactoryMethod = ``type``.GetMethod "SetHostFactory"

    let Create () = ctor.Invoke (Array.empty) :?> IHostBuilder
    let ConfigureHostBuilder (builder : IHostBuilder) (hostBuilder : obj) =
        ConfigureHostBuilderMethod.Invoke (builder, [| hostBuilder |])
        |> ignore
    let EntryPointCompleted (builder : IHostBuilder) (``exception`` : exn) =
        EntryPointCompletedMethod.Invoke (builder, [| ``exception`` |])
        |> ignore
    let SetHostFactory (builder : IHostBuilder) (func : Func<string[], obj>) =
        SetHostFactoryMethod.Invoke (builder, [| func |]) |> ignore

module HostFactoryResolver =

    open System.Reflection

    let private ``type`` =
        typedefof<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory<_>>.Assembly.GetType
            "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver"

    let private ResolveHostFactoryMethod = ``type``.GetMethod "ResolveHostFactory"

    let ResolveHostFactory
        (
            assembly : Assembly,
            waitTimeout : TimeSpan Nullable,
            stopApplication : bool Nullable,
            configureHostBuilder : Action<obj>,
            entrypointCompleted : Action<exn>
        ) =
        let args : obj array = [| assembly; waitTimeout; stopApplication; configureHostBuilder; entrypointCompleted |]
        ResolveHostFactoryMethod.Invoke (null, args) :?> Func<string[], obj>

and used it to create my host (where I plan to replace some services).
static member GetServerHost<'EntryPoint> () =
    let assembly = typeof<'EntryPoint>.Assembly
    let deferredHostBuilder =
        DeferredHostBuilder
            .Create()
            .UseEnvironment(Environments.Development)
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration (fun config ->
                config.AddInMemoryCollection (
                    kvp HostDefaults.ApplicationKey (assembly.GetName().Name)
                    |> Seq.singleton
                )|> ignore
            )

    let configureHostBuilder = DeferredHostBuilder.ConfigureHostBuilder deferredHostBuilder
    let entrypointCompleted = DeferredHostBuilder.EntryPointCompleted deferredHostBuilder
    let func =
        HostFactoryResolver.ResolveHostFactory (
            assembly,
            Nullable (),
            Nullable false,
            configureHostBuilder,
            entrypointCompleted
        )

    DeferredHostBuilder.SetHostFactory deferredHostBuilder func
    deferredHostBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults (fun builder ->
        builder.UseTestServer () |> ignore
    )

But when I start my host
member this.GetClient () = this.clientHost.Services.GetRequiredService<OpenIddictClientService> ()

member val TestContext = Unchecked.defaultof<TestContext> with get, set

[<TestInitialize>]
member this.TestInitialize () =
    let port = Random.Shared.Next (49152, 65535)
    let serverBuilder =
        ConsoleUserAuthIntegrationTests
            .GetServerHost<Server.Program.App>()
            .ConfigureWebHost (fun builder ->
                builder.UseUrls ($"http://*:{port}/") |> ignore)
    this.serverHost <- serverBuilder.Build ()
    this.serverHost.RunAsync () |> ignore

it does not listen to the port.
How can I fix that?

I discovered that calling UseTestServer in replaces the Kestrel with the in-process HTTP server .ConfigureWebHostDefaults (fun builder -> builder.UseTestServer () |> ignore)
So removing this call fixed the issue
